# Getting first element of a JSON array

Tags: php, json, curl, mapbox

Using MapBox, I am trying to show a route duration and distance. I am using a CURL request to pull the directions fine.

I am trying to get the distance and duration which is in the JSON response `routes` array

**First part of JSON response**

```
  {"routes":[{"weight_name":"auto","weight":9161.043,"duration":9875.611,"distance":178237.406,"legs":[{"via_waypoints":[],"annotation":{"distance":
```

**My Code**

```
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $Duration=$response['routes'][0]['duration'];
    echo $Duration;
```

This is echoing only `{`

What am i doing wrong as I want it to show `9875.611` as per the response?

Comment: curl will be returning a string; you need to call `json_decode()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are receiving from the API is a JSON string not a JSON Array. You are trying to access the routes as you are dealing with a JSON Array. You should Json decode the curl response just before accessing the 'routes' element. I just modified your PHP code as below

```
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 $arr = json_decode($response);
 $Duration=$arr['routes'][0]['duration'];
 echo $Duration;
```

Comment: Thanks, this still echo's `{` 

**Code** 

`$response = curl_exec($curl);
$Duration=$response['routes'][0]['duration'];
  echo $Duration; `